# Tabbed content in a SharePoint page

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I’ve got a requirement to create tabs for content displayed on a web page, so that a user doesn’t have to scroll vertically to read all the content.

Is there a way for jQuery to automatically divide page content into chunks and wrap that into tabs? I’m sure I saw something somewhere once…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery UI [tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) plugin is what you need.

Example:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').tabs();
});
</script>

<div id="example">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="ahah_1.html"><span>Content 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ahah_2.html"><span>Content 2</span></a></li>
         <li><a href="ahah_3.html"><span>Content 3</span></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The user creating the content would have to be familiar with html for this solution to work?

Comment: Really depends on the implementation. I would suggest checking out the examples on the link provided, I could paste them here but there doesn't seem to be much point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to add WebPartZones so that I can have multiple WebParts in each tab.